# Mule: Closing stream and queued-asynchronous

Tags: java, mule, mule-el

I have a flow which I have just converted from synchronous into queued-asynchronous.
At some point in a foreach, I am opening a file and setting a FileInputStream, as follows:

```
public class FileAsStream {
    // return a fileInputStream.
    public FileInputStream fileAsStream(String fileName) {
        File file = new File(fileName);
        FileInputStream fis = null;
        try {
            fis = new FileInputStream(file);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            return fis;
        }
    }
```

The FileInputStream then becomes my payload, and I'm sending it off to http or sftp endpoints. When the flow was synchronous, I could then run #[payload.close()] and close the stream. But now that it is asynchronous it doesn't look like I can. It fails when I attempt to close the stream. My question is whether it matters if I close the stream or not. Does Mule wrap up objects created in the context of the flow? Or do I need to somehow close the stream after it has been sent to the endpoint?

Comment: Why does it fail? What's the exception? I don't see why going async would prevent closing it, except if you try to serialize the payload at some point. Also why using a custom component for doing something the file transport can do for you via the requester interface?

Comment: I have long looked for a solution like the one you suggest. Using the requester interface. I will look into this instead of using my custom class. I simply did not know/find that it was possible in Mule without custom code. Thanks,